# shelljs to execute a shell script part of npm module

Tags: node.js, shelljs

I am creating a a little nodejs based cli. What I require is ability to call a shell script thats part of my npm module (thats pushed to a npm registry).

I was looking at `shelljs` and I found it could execute scripts from the file system. However I am looking at something like `shell.execute(require('./execute.sh'))`.

Is there a way to accomplish this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using `get-installed-path` to the path of the shell script within the bundle.